# The D-Link DWA-131 Wi-Fi adapter is not working on Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, wireless, wifi

I succeeded in doing remote access using SSH (through an Ethernet cable), but I am not able to connect the Raspberry Pi to Wi-Fi. I bought the D-Link [DWA-131](http://us.dlink.com/products/connect/wireless-n-nano-usb-adapter/) USB dongle as it was stated to work out of the box and recommended in *[RPi USB Wi-Fi Adapters](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters)*. My Raspberry Pi detects this dongle.

I tried the steps in *[Setting up Wifi with the Command Line](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-occidentalis)* and *[How to Setup Wi-Fi On Your Raspberry Pi via the Command Line](http://www.howtogeek.com/167425/how-to-setup-wi-fi-on-your-raspberry-pi-via-the-command-line/)* at two separate times with no success.

I even installed "wicd" on my Raspberry Pi, but I am still unable to connect.

What is the proper configuration to get this one working?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? (Check `/var/log/messages` or `dmesg`.)

Comment: The page *[D-Link DWA-131 (N300, USB, WiFi Adapter)](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-11-16-d-link-dwa-131-n300-usb-wifi-adapter)* (Linux-Hardware-Guide.com) has very good background information on the DWA-131 (but it doesn't contain the information in dloinaz's answer). Two different chipsets are used for the DWA-131: hardware version A1 uses the Realtek RTL8191SU chipset and hardware version B1 uses the Realtek RTL8192CU chipset.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

`cat /sys/module/8192cu/parameters/rtw_power_mgnt`

If it returns 1, the you need to create file `/etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf`

1. Create the file

   `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf`

   # Enable DLINK

   # Disable power saving

   options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0
2. Reboot the system

   `sudo reboot`
3. Once it reboots, run previous command again and confirm it return 0

`cat /sys/module/8192cu/parameters/rtw_power_mgnt`

If so, it should be working properly now

Comment: For me the file was: `/sys/module/8192eu/parameters/rtw_power_mgnt`

Answer (score 1):

The configuration in */etc/network/interfaces* must match
that of the wireless router. For the very common scenario of using
[WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004) and a [pre-shared key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-shared_key) (PSK), the setup in the first reference,
*Setting up Wifi with the Command Line*, actually works.

This worked in my test setup:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "Your SSID"
    wpa-psk "Your extremely-high-entropy password"

iface default inet dhcp
```

After rebooting the Raspberry Pi, the configuration can be tested by issuing `ifconfig` at 
the command line and looking for a line with "inet addr" in the section for "wlan0". Example:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:19:8f:9a:26:0e
          inet addr:192.168.3.101  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2917 errors:0 dropped:37 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2911 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:380554 (371.6 KiB)  TX bytes:356183 (347.8 KiB)
```

In this example the [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server in the wireless router has assigned 
the [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) 192.168.3.101 to the Raspberry Pi.

When the configuration works as required, the line with "eth0" in /etc/network/interfaces can be removed or commented out and then access to the Internet
through the wireless connection will work.

I tried with power supplies of varying quality, including a 
high-quality lab power supply set at 5.2 volt and with/without a 
powered USB hub, but plugging the DWA-131 straight 
into the Raspberry Pi and using a quite weak power supply 
with a long lead worked equally well (the voltage at the USB 
port was as low as 4.18 volt).

Test setup:

- Operating system: [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) as bundled with [NOOBS 1.3.10](http://director.downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS/images/NOOBS-2014-09-12/NOOBS_v1_3_10.zip) (2014-09). (The kernel version is 3.12.28.)
- Firmware: 2014-09-08 (3f2f2607186be72e4945cfa8edc77872dfc73195).
- Raspberry Pi: model B, rev. 1
- Wireless router: [WRT54GL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series#WRT54GL) v. 1.1.
- USB Wi-Fi adapter: D-Link DWA-131, hardware version B1, firmware version 2.01.
- [dloinaz's disabling of power saving](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12849/the-d-link-dwa-131-wi-fi-adapter-is-not-working-on-raspberry-pi/13165#13165) was applied, but it is not known how crucial this change is.