# Raspberry Pi 3 and DLink N300 not working

Tags: pi-3, wifi, driver

I'm trying to get an additional wifi working on my raspberry pi 3.

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:2838 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL2838 DVB-T
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1546:01a8 U-Blox AG 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0403:7028 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So the device shows up in `lsusb`, but that's as far as it gets.
I'm not a RPI expert, I've been following many "tutorials" trying to make it work, however, I can't get the adapter to even show up in `ifconfig`.
The built-in wifi works fine, however, I need an additional wifi connection.
Any tips?

Thanks all!

Comment: Unplug the device, plug it back in then can you post the last few lines in the output from a `dmesg` command that shows the kernel seeing the new USB device and trying to get the drivers loaded for it.

Comment: The first thing to do is install a supported version of Raspbian

Comment: @Dougie
I've pasted it here https://pastebin.com/fYHUkvru

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=33588

Comment: `sudo wget http://www.fars-robotics.net/install-wifi -O /usr/bin/install-wifi`
 `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/install-wifi`
 `sudo install-wifi -h`

Comment: @Dougie What are your cryptic comments are meaning? Using a driver?

Comment: That stuff will get Mr. Engman's driver (as documented on the Raspberry Pi forum).

Comment: Might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/12849/44221